# Custom op is replaced by another ops

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite

I need to use Conv1D layers in a speech recognition model to run on microcontrollers. Since TFLM doesn't support Conv1D I thought to use the keras layer class: after that I tried to define and register the op to be supported by TF Lite.

However it seems that my op is replaced by another ops. How can it be possible?

Comment: According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39823, the recent TF version does support Conv1D, for example, TF 2.4 or beyond. How about using the recent TF version? You might not need to implement this custom op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFLite supports Conv1D through wrappring the existing Conv2D op with a Reshape op already. Did you try the conversion? I think your case is already supported by the TensorFlow Lite builtin op set. If not, please file a feature request at the TensorFlow github.

Comment: I mean the TF's Conv1D operator will be replaced with a TFLite Conv2D op (+Reshape op) during TF to TFLite conversion. You don't need to implement this feature on your side.

Comment: Even though there is a custom Conv1D op, the TF to TFLite conversion always favors the TFLite Conv2D op since it is a builtin op. To use the custom conv1d op, you need to modify the TFLite converter as well..

Comment: So something like this: converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([conv1d.get_concrete_function(x)])
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tflite_model = converter.convert() wouldn't work in this  particular case?

Comment: There is no such option. The converter always places a TFLite conv2d op for the TF conv1d op regardless of the allow_custom_ops flag's value since it favors the TFLite builtin ops over custom ops.